# angularjs ng-click getting info from child element

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get info from the ng-click element. When I log $event from clicked element I get the right info but when I click the child element of then I get the info about the child and not the parent where the ng-click is set. Here is the fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/g3x2ndyc/5/.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
app.controller('appCtr', function($scope) {
$scope.testThis = function(evt){
  //evt.stopPropagation();
 // evt.preventDefault();
console.log(evt.srcElement.offsetLeft)
console.log(evt.srcElement.offsetWidth)
console.log('____________________________')
}
});
```

Comment: What info do you want? Do you mean the parent $scope?

Comment: Another thing you can do, is add `pointer-events:none;` to the CSS of your inner-div; you will then only see mouse events for the div that has the ng-click

Comment: Thats NICE. Thanks Darren

Comment: UPDATED - But didn't work in Firefox
evt.srcElement is undefined

Answer (score 1):

use evt.currentTarget not evt.srcElement (that one is mainly for IE).

Look at fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g3x2ndyc/11/

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
app.controller('appCtr', function($scope) {
    $scope.testThis = function(evt){
        console.log(evt.currentTarget.offsetLeft)
        console.log(evt.currentTarget.offsetWidth)
        console.log('____________________________')
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly what you are ultimately trying to do, but you can just pass the id in to the click event then grab the position based on that.

```
ng-click="myevent('idName')

myevent(id) {
  jquery('#'+id).position();
}
```

Comment: I trying to get the position of element which I am clicking. Here is the jsfiddle link 
http://jsfiddle.net/g3x2ndyc/5/.

Comment: This worked thank you, but I had to add Jquery. There should be some way with Angular.